# Terminal does not respond

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I'm having problems with my terminal. When I boot up, the terminal starts at startup, I'm using zsh (prezto) it may take a while for my terminal to be fully operational. My problem right now (just occurred) is that my terminal does not respond entirely. It just stays like this:

[image]

Opening another tab does not help and neither does opening a new window. Searching for a solution on google is not fruitful either. Also, when I open a new tab and close it immediately elementary logs me out closing all applications.

Comment: Have you installed anything else that might conflict with this installation? Perhaps another terminal application? Do you still have this issue in Loki?

Comment: It's now showing right now and I think the terminal is not responding because of a docker application that was running on background that was very large.

Comment: Do you mean "now" or "not"? Have you tried deactivating the docker application to see what happens?

Comment: I mean not. Yeah, it's already fine now. Deleted the docker container that was causing the problem.